How to unwrap variable that is initialized and can never be nil without extraneous code
I'm providing the class below as a quick example, but my real world scenarios are much more complex, so I'm not looking to change the variable initialization aspect or the fact that this property is optional.
I'm looking for feedback on the function itself.  The way it's currently written, XCode will show the following error message.  I'm looking for any way to return the String, which can never be nil, from the function without extraneous / unnecessary code (examples further down of things I'd like to avoid if possible).  If it's not possible to avoid the unnecessary code, then I understand, but I'm curious if there are other ways I haven't thought of yet.

Value of optional type 'String?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'String'

public class Thing {

  var information: String? = nil

  func getInformation() -> String {
    if let information {
      return information
    } else {
      information = functionThatReturnsNonOptionalString()
      return information // Error here
    }
  }

}

I'd like to avoid the following:
Coalescing (I'll use this one if there's no other way), which I think is unnecessary because information will never be nil:
return information ?? ""

Dummy returns, which I think is unnecessary because information will never be nil:
if let information {
} else {
  return ""
}

Throwing, which I think is unnecessary because information will never be nil:
if let information {
} else {
  throw Error()
}

What am I overlooking?  I'm not an expert, so let me know if there's something obvious that I've missed.  Note that I'm not looking for opinions, just any way this can be unwrapped without extraneous code.  Not sure what extraneous code is?  Any code that doesn't need to exist because the value can never be nil.  I'm just looking for ideas on how other people might have solved this problem because I'm not yet an expert in swift.
Thanks!

If you're so sure information will never be nil, isn't it a good thing to throw if you turn out to be wrong, rather than having the program silently continue with a broken invariant?

@user2357112 The value is set in the line immediately prior, but for any situations that have any potential for it to be unset, I would throw, yes.

I wonder why would you make an object that will never be nil optional. It doesn’t make any sense.

As mentioned the last time you asked the same question, just do information ?? "abc"

@Joakim Danielson As mentioned in my question, "my real world scenarios are much more complex", but perhaps I did not provide enough complexity in the question for everyone to understand that I am not setting it to a string literal, so I will update it now to reflect that.  Thank you for helping me to clarify the question.

You can use lazy var for example

@Leo Dabus It will be nil prior to initialization, which is done in the function

@Cy-4AH I'll take a look at your suggestion!

Taking all answers and comments into account, you simply make a false assumption: you say that the value is never nil, but in fact it actually can be nil. Your code should either explicitly check invariants, or you need a better design, so that indeed your value can never be nil (for example, initialising it in an init).

If the string can never be nil and functionThatReturnsString returns a non-optional an alternative is to declare information as empty string
public class Thing {

  var information = ""

  func getInformation() -> String {
     if information.isEmpty {
       information = functionThatReturnsString()
     }
     return information
  }
}

Or – picking up the suggestion of Leo Dabus – initialize information lazily
public class Thing {

  lazy var information : String = {
      self.functionThatReturnsString()
  }()
}


That does work for String, but would get dicey when applying the same coding principle to other classes, like Int

If it needs to be an optional type but you’re sure it won’t be nil during runtime, you can use a force unwrap:
return information!

Or even simply:
let nonOptionalInformation = functionThatReturnsNonOptionalString()
information = nonOptionalInformation
return nonOptionalInformation

Force unwrap will produce a crash at runtime if information is nil. Another thing you can do if this value is optional for ease of initialization, is declare it like this:
var information: String!

Which enables implicit force unwrapping on every access of information. This will also cause a crash if information is EVER accessed and is nil.

I've found one possible answer below.  Just wanted to share in case anyone else comes across this in the future.
  func getInformation() -> String {
    if let information {
      return information
    } else {
      let information = "abc"
      self.information = information
      return information
    }
  }


What has self got to do with this, it’s not part of the question?

@JoakimDanielson The question is about a class, so it has access to self to reference class properties.  I did not include the entire class in the answer, but see the question above.

What you are showing is the flaw in your assumption "I'm looking for any way to return the String, which can never be nil":  it actually can be nil.  You are just returning a String which is not nil, in case the object's string is nil.

And worse, you are lazily initialising information as a side effect of the function. That is not something you should do here. Either initialise with a default value or use a lazy initialiser as Vadian suggests

A struct can also be referenced using self so that is not relevant, what I am reacting to is that you are adding requirements indirectly that wasn't part of the question which is confusing.
